# Changing from @ManagedBean to @Named doesn't work

Tags: jsf, glassfish, cdi

I'm trying to set up a simple JSF project.

I created a new Dynamic Web Project and adjusted its facets:

[image]

Afterwards I added the class MessageServerBean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class MessageServerBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

And an XHTML file:

```
<h:body>

    Hello from Facelets
    <br />
    Message is: #{messageServerBean.message}
    <br />
    Message Server Bean is: #{messageServerBean}    

</h:body>
```

When I execute it, everything works as intended:

```
Hello from Facelets 
Message is: Hello World! 
Message Server Bean is: bean.MessageServerBean@30ecf01b:
```

---

But after changing from JSF Bean to CDI Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped; // changed
import javax.inject.Named; // changed

@SessionScoped
@Named // changed
public class MessageServerBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

The content from the bean are no longer loaded:

```
Hello from Facelets 
Message is: 
Message Server Bean is:
```

In the `beans.xml` the `Bean-Discovery-Mode` is set to `all`.

Comment: What application server are you deploying this to?

Comment: @ernest_k: I'm using Glassfish 5

Comment: And the deployment/bootstrap log shows no error...?

Comment: @ernest_k: Neither the `Console`, nor the `Error Log` show any errors.

Comment: I think this will take someone who knows how that application server works. I've replaced your `javabeans` tag with `glassfish`, to attract that audience (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: In your 'working' example ypu have a wrong combination of `Sessionscoped` (CDI) and `ManagedBean` (JSF). Your bean duscovery is the most likely problem. Try using a searchengine more

Comment: @Kukeltje: Did you mean the wrong import? My bad, I changed it. The bean-discovery is set to `all`.